# MOSFET relay connections to control a 3V motor

Tags: motor, mosfet, control

I need to turn a 1A, 3V motor on and off with a touch switch.  I bought Omron [653-G3VM-61-AR](http://www.omron.com/ecb/products/pdf/en-g3vm_61ar_dr.pdf) and quickly smoked it.  I had the battery + connected thru a 300 Ohm resistor to the touch switch (to get the current down to 10mA) then to one terminal of my MOSFET, grounding the other terminal on the same side to ground.  I connected the same battery + to the terminal of the Mofset with the dot by it, the other terminal to the motor then to ground.  Obviously this is incorrect.

I can't afford to keep smoking these $20 components, so any help you can give me will be appreciated.  The side that I hooked the control current to was the side with the transistors, the side I hooked the load to seems to be the "coil" side, by Omron's schematic.

Obviously I know little to nothing about electronics, so I need all the help I can get.

Comment: The Omron Mofset schematic can be found on the data sheet at http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Omron/G3VM-61AR/?qs=%2fha2pyFaduiurn9hODhUQGraRSLVYpa9E0k8QyOJnY2r1nRTK5NkVA%3d%3d

Answer (score 2):

Your circuit was connected incorrectly:

Pin 1 is the one nearest the large circular mark, at the left lower side when you hold the part with the printed text correctly oriented and facing you. Pins 2, 3 and 4 go anticlockwise from there.

The Omron MOSFET relay datasheet indicates that your control current needs to be flowing between pins 1 and 2, with positive going to pin 1. Pin 2 will go to ground. Reversing these two pins will not work.

The load is switched by wiring it via pins 3 and 4: Thus 3 and 4 are wired in series with your load, like a push-button would be. The current flow on the switched side (pins 3 and 4) can be in either direction. For convenience, connect pin 3 to Ground, it being closer to pin 2.

Ensure that the motor does not draw more than 1.2 amperes even at startup or stall conditions: The "Recommended Operating Conditions" section states 2 amperes, which realistically works out to 1.2 Amperes at maximum recommended operating temperature (65 degrees C). This rating reduction is as per the specification for derating at 20 mA per degree Centigrade over 25 degrees.

It is worth noting that when a motor or other inductive load is switched off, a fairly high reverse voltage spike can develop across the switch contacts: Typically clamping or bypass diodes are connected to safely drain this spike so it does not damage the MOSFET switches. Many MOSFET packages integrate these diodes internally, but it is still worth adding external diodes in case that's what is "smoking" your relays.